# Angular2 - Http create json from empty response

Tags: angular

Hello I have this code:

```
save<T>(url: string, data:any, headers = null): Observable<T>{
return this.http
            .post(url, data, headers)
            .map(x =>{
                return x.json() as T
            } )
            .catch(error => {
                this.app.handleError(error, errorMessage);
                return Observable.throw(error);
            }).share();
}
```

And when i send request to action which return empty response (_body: "")
I have error `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` in `x.json()`

How to check when body isnt empty? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.map(x =>{
  return (x._body ? x.json() : null) as T
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Test this,

```
.map(x =>(x._body ? x.json() : null) as T)
```